# lib for solving nonlinear optimization tasks in .net

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I trying to implement SVM implementation. During this problem I need to solve nonlinear optimization problem. Could anyone advice me a lib for that for .NET platform
thanks a lot.

If someone could advice something which he used for SVM it will be brilliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that acronym SVM in your question means Support Vector Machine. In this case you need solver for linear or quadratic programming (depends on the formulation). I can name several libraries for .NET platform that contains linear or quadratic programming solvers:

- [NMath from CenterSpace](http://www.centerspace.net/)
- [FinMath from RTMath](https://www.rtmath.net/products/finmath/)
- [Extreme Optimization](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/)

All of them are commercial software (but most of provide special academic license for non-commercial use for small amount of money). Also, most of the professional libraries for numerical optimization like [MOSEK](http://www.mosek.com/), [CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimizer/), [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) etc. contain wrappers for .NET platform.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what SVM stands for. But I know that [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/) offers some good optimization algorithms in .net. Further, you could consider to wrap [NLOpt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) which offers a lot of different algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with SVM (Support Vector Machines?), but for gradient-based large-scale nonlinear optimization with potentially non-linear constraints there is a .NET "adapter" to the [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) optimizer [here](https://github.com/cureos/csipopt).

If you require a derivative-free method for fewer variables, you can find a C# port of Michael Powell's derivative-free COBYLA2 optimizer [here](https://github.com/cureos/cscobyla).

Answer (score 1):

I try to use Accord.net for that purpose mainly because it's free.

Comment: Plus, it would be worth to mention that Accord.NET can be found on https://code.google.com/p/accord/ and it does include both SVMs as well as Quadratic Optimization solvers. And it is free.